# Spotlight Re-Indexing at Startup

Tags: spotlight, indexing

I have a 15" Macbook Pro Early 2011 and OS X 10.9.2. Spotlight is starting to re-index process when I logged in. I want to know: is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: does it happen on every login? how long does the indexing take?

Comment: The question is how long the re-indexing is running. If it's just a minute this is normal behavior but if it's running for 30 min something's messed up.

Comment: @KevinGrabher Yes, it doing on every login and index process is taking ~3 minute.

Comment: @Kovah It doesn't take 30 minute but index process is making OS X unusable.

Comment: Well this is not a normal behavior. Check the access rights of your system with the disk utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mac OS X will often index the spotlight at startup. Depending on how many files are on your computer, this process will range from a few seconds to a few minutes (if your computer is terribly slow). I hope this helps!